# Countdown characters in textbox to label not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In this scernario, I have a textbox and a label of which the label is a countdown of the remaining characters available in the textbox. E.g. "239 characters remaining".

I personally want to use the javascript function a couple of times, so I want to pass to the variables to the function. These being, maxlength (for length), textbox (for the field) and label (for the counter label).

However, the issue I have is that this is simply not working. Just to make sure it wasn't just an IE thing, I tested it in Firefox 18 and it's also producing the same where where label does not change... It's almost like the onKeyUp method is note being called.

Anyways my code.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function countCharacters(textbox, label, maxcount) {
        var count = parseInt(document.getElementById(textbox).value.length);
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = maxcount - count;
    }
```

**Label and Textbox**

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment01" runat="server" CssClass="txt" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Visible="false" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbCommentCount01" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false" CssClass="size11_text_blurb"></asp:Label>
```

**Code Behind**

```
tbComment01.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "countCharacters(" + tbComment01.ClientID + "," + lbCommentCount01.ClientID + ", 500)");
```

Cheers all!

Trent

Comment: have you checked what you are getting in argument of countCharacters using alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because there were no quotes on the parameters to your function. Therefore it was passing the HTML element objects and not their Ids. You were thus using `getElementById` on an object and not the ID [which should be a string]

Before, your function looked like

```
onKeyUp="countCharacters(tbComment01,lbCommentCount01, 500)"
```

therefore passing `HTMLTextAreaElement` instead of string "tbComment01"

And should be

```
onKeyUp="countCharacters('tbComment01','lbCommentCount01', 500)"
```

This should fix it, note that I have added the single quotes from code-behind

```
tbComment01.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "countCharacters('" + tbComment01.ClientID + "','" + lbCommentCount01.ClientID + "', 500)");
```

OR better

```
tbComment01.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp",String.Format("countCharacters('{0}','{1}', 500) ", tbComment01.ClientID, lbCommentCount01.ClientID)
```

Comment: Thanks @codingbiz, the single quotes around it were the issue. Also much appreciated the better way of laying it out. Much easier to read and I shouldn't of been so lazy to write it like that to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is due to lbCommentCount01 still being `Visible="false"` serverside, when `Visible="false"`, controls are not rendered to page. (This is to save bandwidth.)

If you want to make the control initially invisible, but turn it visible in javascript, make sure to use `style="display:none;"` and in the code remove that with:

```
document.getElementById('yourid').style.display = '';
```

Comment: Hmm hadn't seen the no quotes >.< Won't be stealing codingbiz's answer though, since it's still possible this is happening.

Comment: Sorry. This is an ommision on my behalf. The Label is not visible until a certain button is clicked. Could it be becuase it's hidden to begin with that it is causing the label to be stagnent?

Comment: @TrentSteenholdt No, that should not matter. Once you PostBack (click the button) and set `<labelname>.Visible = true;` __before__ Page_PreRender finished, it will be rendered to the browser.

Comment: Just looked at the other answer provided by @codingbiz, the visible="false" suggestion did not play a part in the issue (Again apologies for not putting this in the question itself that it becomes visible on a  button click before a user is typing into the field.).